# Parse an Online Code Repository in Java

Tags: java, parsing, github

I'm trying to figure out a way to parse a Java repository hosted by GitHub from within a java program. I've looked at GitHub's API, but it's quite confusing.

I'm using this for an IRC bot; the idea would be for an IRC user to type "!docs [class] [methodname]" and get the docs notice'd to them.

All I'm looking for is a way to (hopefully) easily find the javadocs above a method.

For example, in this case if I put in "!doc Entity getBounds()", I'd like it to find this:
[image]

and give me everything in the javadoc tags as a string.

EDIT: Additionally, I don't believe that GitHub's API even offers this kind of functionality.

Comment: what have you tried so far, what exactly doesn't work. did you check java bindings to github api? http://develop.github.com/p/libraries.html

Comment: Well all I have tried is the github api. I can't get it to auth me, nor can I find any examples that I can understand (yea I looked at "examples":p )

I googled around and tried to find online repository parsers but couldn't really find what I'm looking for. I could parse it on my own with an inputstream but I feel like something like this has to exist already.

Comment: You will have to ask a clearer question for any chance of a useful answer. Show the code that isn't working etc. [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for a GitHub-type answer. Any HTML or page parser will do, where I can navigate a hosted repository pretty easily, and find code as well. :O

Comment: Why not interact with git directly, get it to pull the latest revision, and parse the files and extract the information from the files that you want, this way it would work with any git repository, not just github. If you don't want to do that you can access the raw files on github like this: https://raw.github.com/user_name/path/to/source.java

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out on accident, actually.

The Doclet API provides everything I was looking for. All I have to do is download the files from GitHub.

Check it out:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/javadoc/doclet/